# How to find number of strings generated by permuting the given string satisfying the below conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**The question goes like this-**

How many strings can be generated by permuting the characters of "**abbbbcccdeff**" such that there are only 3 mismatchings and the rest 9 are same ?

**My attempt-**

Obviously, If the string was having only distinct characters(like-"**abcdefghijkl**") then the answer would have been- 2*(12C9)=440 strings[as there are 12 characters and 9 of them have to be same]. I can calculate this for strings having distinct characters only, but I am failing to generalise this for strings with repeating characters.

I can manually find all pairs,but this method is very time-consuming,like-for the case of- **"abbbcc"** there comes a total of 12 such strings . These are-
 **bbbcac**,**bbbcca**,**bbcbac**,**bbcbca**,**bcbbac**,**bcbbca**,**cabbbc**,**cabbcb**,**cbabbc**,**cbabcb**,**cbbabc**,**cbbacb**

**Where I am failing?**

I need a quick solution(some kind of generalised formula) instead of counting it manually

Answer (score 0):

There is $1$ letter with $4$ occurrences, $1$ letter with $3$ occurrences, $1$ letter with $2$ occurrences and $3$ letters with $1$ occurrence. Thus the number of triples of distinct letters is

$$
\binom30(4\cdot3\cdot2)+\binom31(4\cdot3\cdot1)+\binom31(4\cdot2\cdot1)+\binom31(3\cdot2\cdot1)+\binom32(4+3+2)\cdot1+\binom33=24+36+24+18+27+1=130\;.
$$

Each of these can be permuted in $2$ ways, for a total of $2\cdot130=260$ permutations.

Comment: But, brute forcing the string-"abbbbcccdeff"[Using C program] is giving me 260 as the answer

Comment: The answer is `2 * (C(12, 3) - C(4, 3) - C(3, 3) - C(4, 2) * 8 - C(3, 2) * 9 - C(2, 2) * 10) = 260`.

Comment: @RachitBelwariar: Sorry, I'd missed the fact that you can choose more than one of the singletons. I've corrected the answer and am now also gettting $260$.

Comment: @WhatsUp
I got everything in your explanation, except the fact that why you are mutiplying C(4,2) with 8, C(3,2) with 9, C(2,2) with 10 while C(4,3),C(3,3) are multiplied by 1 ?

Comment: @RachitBelwariar The term `C(4, 3)` means choosing `3` identical letter **b**, similarly for the term `C(3, 3)`. The term `C(4, 2) * 8` means choosing `2` identical letter **b** and `1` other letter, similarly for the terms `C(3, 2) * 9` and `C(2, 2) * 10`.

Comment: @WhatsUp 
Ok, can you generalise this for a string of length-'n' having its characters as-
aaaa...(Na times)bb...(Nb times)cc...c....kk....kkk(Nk times), such that Na+Nb+Nc+....Nk =n ? for two cases-
1) When there are only 3 mismatches and 'n-3' are same?
2) When there are only 2 mismatches and 'n-2' are same?

Comment: @joriki
Can you generalise this for a string of length-'n' having its characters as- aaaa...(Na times)bb...(Nb times)cc...c....kk....kkk(Nk times), such that Na+Nb+Nc+....Nk =n ? for two cases- 1) When there are only 3 mismatches and 'n-3' are same? 2) When there are only 2 mismatches and 'n-2' are same?

Comment: @RachitBelwariar: This comment thread is not the place to ask wide-ranging follow-up questions; you can post those as questions of their own. I think if you understand the present answer you should be able to make those generalisations yourself; if not, feel free to ask about the present answer.