# How to find number of strings generated by permuting the given string and satisfying the given constraints??

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**The question goes like this-**

How many strings can be generated by permuting the characters of the string **"aaaa[Na times]...bb[Nb times]...cc....c....kkk[Nk times]"** such that

> Na+Nb+Nc+...Nk=N(where N is the total number of characters in the string)

1)There are only 3 mismatchings between the permuted string and the original string and the rest 'N-3' characters are same ?

2)There are only 2 mismatchings between the permuted string and the original string and the rest 'N-2' characters are same ?

**Example**-

Like for the case of **"abbbcc"** there comes a total of 12 such strings which have exactly 3 mismatchings and the rest characters are same. These are- **bbbcac,bbbcca,bbcbac,bbcbca,bcbbac,bcbbca,cabbbc,cabbcb,cbabbc,cbabcb,cbbabc,cbbacb**

**My attempt-**

I have genralised the formulaes as shown

1)**For exactly 3 mismatching**-

> $2*(C(N,3)-C(Na,2)-C(Nb,2)-....C(Nk,2)-C(Na,2) * (N-Na)-C(Nb,2) * (N-Nb)....-C(Nk,2) * (N-Nk))$

2)**For exactly 2 mismatching**-

> $C(N,3)-C(Na,2)-C(Nb,2)-....C(Nk,2)$

where **C(x,y)** means combinations of 'y' items from total 'x' items

**Where I am failing?**

I don't know, but somewhere I feel that I am missing the corner cases

**Useful Link**-

[How to find number of strings generated by permuting the given string satisfying the below conditions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694022/how-to-find-number-of-strings-generated-by-permuting-the-given-string-satisfying/1694033?noredirect=1#comment3457690_1694033)

I just want to get confirmed whether my generalised formula is right or not or I am omitting some corner cases in my considerations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these formulas are accurate with the changes to your formulas in bold.

For 3 mismatches:

2*(C(N,3)−C(Na,**3**)−C(Nb,**3**)−....C(Nk,**3**)−C(Na,2)∗(N−Na)−C(Nb,2)∗(N−Nb)....−C(Nk,2)∗(N−Nk))

For 2 mismatches:

C(N,**2**)−C(Na,2)−C(Nb,2)−....C(Nk,2)